# C# function that computes x = |f(x) - f(x-1)|

Tags: c#, function

How would I write a function that computes `x = |f(x) - f(x-1)|`, considering I already have a function that computes `f(x)`?

Comment: `Math.Abs(f(x) - f(x - 1))`?

Comment: Unless `f(x)` is analytically differentiable, you will need to call it explicitly with the two different arguments and subtract them and take the absolute value? What sort of magic were you hoping for here?

Comment: what is f exactly , if f is a method that takes one argument and returns a variable then this is so simple !!

Comment: @Jim Yes. A pair of vertical bars is the mathematical notation for an Absolute Value: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value (aka Magnitude or Modulus - not to be confused with Modulo).

Comment: What is this? an homework?

Comment: @Dai thanks, learned something, that clears it up :)

Comment: For added fun, define `f` as a `Expression<T>` and then dynamically compose `f(x)` and `f(x-1)` at runtime!

Answer (score 0):

In *general case* (we have `Func<T, T> f` lambda which we want to turn into a `Func<T, T>` lambda which returns `|f(x) - f(x-1)|`), it's quite an interesting problem (thanks for Dai, see comments to the question). Let's have fun:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

...

public static partial class FuncExtensions {
  public static Func<T, T> AbsDiff<T>(this Func<T, T> source) {
    if (null == source)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, T>> f = v => source(v);
    MethodInfo abs = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Abs", new Type[] { typeof(T) });

    var one = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(1), typeof(T));

    var body = Expression.Call(abs, Expression.Subtract(
      Expression.Invoke(f, x),
      Expression.Invoke(f, Expression.Subtract(x, one))));

    return Expression.Lambda(body, x).Compile() as Func<T, T>;
 }
```

}

Now, let's test:

```
   Func<double, double> f1 = x => x * x;
   Func<int, int> f2 = x => x;

   // |2*2 - 1*1| == 3
   Console.WriteLine(f1.AbsDiff()(2).ToString());   
   // |5 - 4| == 1
   Console.WriteLine(f2.AbsDiff()(5).ToString());
```

P.S. I suspect, that what's *actually* wanted in the question is [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yzeea2(v=vs.110).aspx) method to call it like

```
   var result = Math.Abs(f(x) - f(x - 1));
```